# How to access files between two projects(Yii1 and Yii2)?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii1.x

I wrote the same project(Front end and back end) using Yii1. Now, I changed the front end using Yii2 but back end are still running with Yii1(But,they are different projects) on same database. The problem is that Yii1 can't access files from Yii2 uploads folders when Yii2 uploads files.Because, back end (Admin site) want to look upload files and also want to update.Is it possible to access each other? How can I handle it? (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: the project you created in `Yii1` how did you implemented the frontend and backend? as far i remember i used to create a module for the admin section as there used to be single app within `protected` folder or did you had 2 separate projects implemented in `yii1`, as `frontend` and `backend`

Comment: I implemented a module for the admin section  to be single app within protected folder in yii1, as frontend and backend. Not 2 separate projects.